# is text preferable over digits?

Tags: data-tables, data-collection

I want to display datasets with a field called "criticality".
This field should contain either a digit from 1 to 3 or texts like "High", "Medium", "Low".
What do you think, which representation is faster for cognitive processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to both earlier answers I suggest that using a combination of color patterns and numbers may be a right solution.

As @Peter said:

> Additionally you can use colors for the different states. Colors are perceived faster than text.

You can use a *traffic lights color state* to indicate the high, medium and low states of the corresponding value of your numbers.

Take a look at this example (try to replace your data and the states with yours):

[image]

So maybe by using **data-ranges and colors**, you are getting to the right solution.

Comment: +1 for colors. That's by far the best to tell instantly. Alternatively shapes, such as a block of varying sizes.

Comment: Just be wary of only using red vs. green. Something like 1-5% of the population are color blind...

Answer (score 3):

There's always ambiguity to a numeric scale, e.g. is DEFCON 1 or DEFCON 5 the most heightened state of readiness for the military? (Hollywood often [gets this wrong](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DefconFive), by the way)  A class 1 cleanroom is cleaner than a class 10 clean room, but a BSL 4 lab has more safeguards than a BSL 3 lab.

Outside of cases where the numbers correspond to a very specific definition that users have been trained on, succinct words like "High", "Medium", and "Low" are unambiguous and don't require the user to remap them to an intuitive scale.

Comment: Note though, that if you have a lot of choices, the words start to become problematic because the intermediate terms tend to get confusing. So be careful.

Comment: If you get into the "lots of choices" range where there may be 10 (or even 5) severities, unless you have specific definitions the distinctions between "Severity: 6" and "Severity: 7" rapidly become meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use text, because you don´t have to interpret them. Numbers are symbolic. You have to learn the meaning behind them.

But choose for the three states other terms like:

- High → Very high
- Medium → Significant
- Low → Low

Additionally you can use colors for the different states. Colors are perceived faster than text.

Comment: Why would you break up the very natural sounding High/Medium/Low?  "Very high" vs. "significant" is just confusing

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what words are available to indicate magnitude, but generally for 5 or less I'd generally go with text (low, medium-low, medium, medium-high, high).

If there are more magnitudes than clear, descriptive words, go with numbers, but add a text qualifier to the max and min numbers:

```
1 (least critical)
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 (most critical)
```

Or you could add a simple explanation at the top or bottom of the number list: *1 is least critical, 10 is most critical*.